# Bootstrap popover with ajax requests

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have some basic ajax requests with [Scroll Pagination](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/)
and content with bootstrap popover ready.
here is a little code:

```
            <a href="#" data-aka="popover" rel="popover" data-original-title="A Title 1">
                <dt id="<?php echo $item->post_date ?>">
                    <?php echo $avatar; ?>
                </dt>
                <dd><strong><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></strong><?php echo $content ?>.</dd>
            </a>



      <script>
 jQuery(function(){

jQuery('.sideUpdate').find('a[data-aka=popover]').popover({
html : true,
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'left',
container: '.chatSidebar',
content: function() {
  return jQuery('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
}
});

});

      </script>
```

this works fine with php generated code, but not the appended one. I guess I need to refresh my js to include new anchors or something like this no?

Comment: After `a[data-aka=popover]` are appended you need to initialize `popover` again

Comment: is there no chance to use script only once?

Comment: no, there is no way as the widgets has to initialized in each of the eleemnt

Comment: I see, I did initilise it in plugin 'afterLoad' method and it worked. thanks. can you submit it as an answer?

Comment: Submitted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this without reinitializing the popover:

```
jQuery('.sideUpdate').popover({
    html : true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'left',
    container: '.chatSidebar',
    content: function() {
       return jQuery('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    },
    selector: "a[data-aka=popover]"
});
```

notice `selector` option that actually works similar to delegated events.

Comment: strange but selector option does not work for me, I'm using bootstrap v2.3.1

Comment: Is your `.sideUpdate` also appended on the fly? If so try to use persistent parent elements

Answer (score 0):

After `a[data-aka=popover]` are appended you need to initialize popover again.

ex:

```
$('<a data-aka="dd"></a>').appendTo('container').popover({})
```